# Detecting finger type with mantra fingerprint sensor

Tags: android, fingerprint, fingerprinting

I have mantra MFS100 optical fingerprint sensor, I want to build an android app that shows the type of finger that is being scanned.

I want to make the app such that it can show which finger is being scanned like Thumb or Index.

**Note: I have successfully downloaded the mantra MFS100 Android SDK but there is no any function that can detect the type of finger being scanned**

Below is the function that start capturing the finger data

```
private void StartSyncCapture() {

    // //// Use thread if you want to show preview, else no need to use
    // thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SetTextonuiThread("");
            try {
                FingerData fingerData = new FingerData();
                int ret = mfs100.AutoCapture(fingerData, timeout, true,
                        false);
                if (ret != 0) {
                    SetTextonuiThread(mfs100.GetErrorMsg(ret));
                } else {
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                            fingerData.FingerImage(), 0,
                            fingerData.FingerImage().length);
                    imgFinger.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            imgFinger.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            imgFinger.refreshDrawableState();
                        }
                    });

                    SetTextonuiThread("Capture Success");
                    String log = "\nQuality: " + fingerData.Quality()
                            + "\nNFIQ: " + fingerData.Nfiq()
                            + "\nWSQ Compress Ratio: "
                            + fingerData.WSQCompressRatio()
                            + "\nImage Dimensions (inch): "
                            + fingerData.InWidth() + "\" X "
                            + fingerData.InHeight() + "\""
                            + "\nImage Area (inch): " + fingerData.InArea()
                            + "\"" + "\nResolution (dpi/ppi): "
                            + fingerData.Resolution() + "\nGray Scale: "
                            + fingerData.GrayScale() + "\nBits Per Pixal: "
                            + fingerData.Bpp() + "\nWSQ Info: "
                            + fingerData.WSQInfo();
                    SetLogOnUIThread(log);

                    //////////////////// Extract ANSI Template
                    byte[] tempData = new byte[2000]; // length 2000 is mandatory
                    byte[] ansiTemplate = null;
                    int dataLen = mfs100.ExtractANSITemplate(fingerData.RawData(), tempData);
                    if(dataLen<=0)
                    {
                        if(dataLen==0)
                        {
                            SetTextonuiThread("Failed to extract ANSI Template");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SetTextonuiThread(mfs100.GetErrorMsg(dataLen));
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ansiTemplate = new byte[dataLen];
                        System.arraycopy(tempData, 0, ansiTemplate, 0,
                                dataLen);
                    }
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////

                    //////////////////// Extract ISO Image
                    dataLen=0;
                    tempData = new byte[(mfs100.GetDeviceInfo().Width() * mfs100.GetDeviceInfo().Height())+1078]; 
                    byte[] isoImage = null;
                    dataLen = mfs100.ExtractISOImage(fingerData.RawData(),tempData);
                    if(dataLen<=0)
                    {
                        if(dataLen==0)
                        {
                            SetTextonuiThread("Failed to extract ISO Image");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SetTextonuiThread(mfs100.GetErrorMsg(dataLen));
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isoImage = new byte[dataLen];
                        System.arraycopy(tempData, 0, isoImage, 0,
                                dataLen);
                    }
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////

                    //////////////////// Extract WSQ Image
                    dataLen=0;
                    tempData = new byte[(mfs100.GetDeviceInfo().Width() * mfs100.GetDeviceInfo().Height())+1078];
                    byte[] wsqImage = null;
                    dataLen = mfs100.ExtractWSQImage(fingerData.RawData(),tempData);

                    if(dataLen<=0)
                    {
                        if(dataLen==0)
                        {
                            SetTextonuiThread("Failed to extract WSQ Image");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SetTextonuiThread(mfs100.GetErrorMsg(dataLen));
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wsqImage = new byte[dataLen];
                        System.arraycopy(tempData, 0, wsqImage, 0,
                                dataLen);
                    }
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////

                    SetData2(fingerData,ansiTemplate,isoImage,wsqImage);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                SetTextonuiThread("Error");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Have you come out from the prob?
I am searching tutorial for this from last 2 weeks but couldn't find nothing.
Could you please suggest me from where I can read the documentation and find the demo for it.
Thanks.

Comment: This sample doesn't even work for me, and I'm stuck. I believe you got this sample from `https://download.mantratecapp.com/Forms/UserDownload`. I've checked USB Host, and also connected the scanner to the android device, but still the app shows "No Device Connected". Let me know where I could have been wrong.

Comment: The sample works though, when you download it from the Mantra MFS sdk-->Sample->AndroidStudio , then import the project in android studio , build it and try to run it in the real device (i assume you know how to transfer the apk from system to phone) , then  once your app gets installed , you can see the app running, Now in the app , you have a button called Capture, When you click on it , then only the biometric device light turns on(red) and then you start capturing the finger

Answer (score 2):

Namy, It is not possible to identify the position (e.g. LEFT_INDEX, LEFT_THUMB, RIGHT_INDEX etc) of finger from captured data. You need to manage position of finger from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code help to capture and extract image (WSQ or ISO) or template (ANSI).

You have to use a function to match current fingerprint with a saved fingerprint. For instance with this method: `mfs100.MatchISO`

Comment: @EnvironerInc , Is it useful ?

Comment: mfs100.MatchISO ? what is this? Can you please elaborate? fingerData.ISOTemplate() gives byte array , when we save to database should we save this byte array and then retrieve it to compare/match?

Comment: I want to integrate mfs100 in my android app using flutter. Where can i find the sdk to place in my project?

Comment: @HadiKhan here : https://github.com/MetaLapras/MantraProject

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do Aadhaar implementation
you need to pass PidOptions and get pid_data and device_info for that need to download RDServiceMFS100 from https://download.mantratecapp.com/Forms/UserDownload then import to android that was old version so need to do some changes like add google maven (give autosuggestion by android studio) then need to replace old constraint to this
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3' after that ready to test and put on your code where you want.

Comment: You should post some code which demonstrates your approach.